# Creating dynamic pages within a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this function:

```
var getData = function (obj) {

    for(var i = 0, j = localStorage.length; i < j; i ++) {
        var newKey = localStorage.key(i);
        var newValue = localStorage.getItem(newKey);    
        var newObj = JSON.parse(newValue);
        var ulListView = $('#container').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="minus" data-split-theme="c" data-inset="true" id="ulOrigin'+i+'"></ul>');
        var dynPage = $(newObj[1].value).trigger('create');     
        //var dynPage = $('<div data-role = "page" id = "'+newObj[1].value+'"><div data-role = "header"></div><div data-role = "content"></div><div data-role = "footer"></div>"</div>');       
        var insideLi = $('#ulOrigin'+i).append('<li><a href="'+dynPage+'"><img src="images/'+newObj[0].value+'.png"><h2>'+newObj[1].value+'</h2><p>'+newObj[0].value+'</p></a><a href = "#deleteObject" data-rel = "popup" data-position-to = "window" data-transition = "pop">Delete Entry</a></li>');     
        var pageNum = $('#ulOrigin'+i);
        console.log(newObj);

    }


};
```

I'm trying to create a dynamic page with the name taken from the `newObj[1].value`. When accessing the link, the error I get is `Error Loading Page`. In the console I have: `OPTIONS file:///home/<address>/[object%20Object]` marked as an error as well.

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3.0

Comment: dynPage is not a string

Comment: Huangism, thanks for your prompt answer. So you're saying that dynPage can not go under the <a href = ""> ?

Comment: well it can but you see the result. dynPage is supposed to be your href URL so it should be a string but in your case, it is an object. The trigger create doesn't need to be assigned to dynPage, basically what I am saying is the href is incorrect and it is currently using dynPage as the entire href. dynPage = $(newObj[1].value).trigger('create'); As you can see dynPage is not an actual URL

Comment: Alright, so I'm using dynPage.selector, which (according to 'typeof') returs a string: "bla bla" with a space in between. I then tried to pass the string to the id. I don't get the same error, but the page doesn't open. I guess I should create a different question, right ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is dynPage is not a string, in your current implementation you have

```
var dynPage = $(newObj[1].value).trigger('create');
```

followed by

```
var insideLi = $('#ulOrigin'+i).append('<li><a href="'+dynPage+'">....
```

I am only assuming you get the error when you click on the href from above. I don't know exactly how create works but the href should point to a page so your href will have a correct URL.

If you are indeed getting the error when you click on the link created by your code, then you can update the question with your latest code and also add the generated html of that link so we can see exactly what's going on.